# parsing skaffold config: error parsing skaffold configuration file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, web-deployment, skaffold

So, I'm trying to automate docker build and push process and as well as the kubectl apply deployment process and for this, I have created a skaffold config file in main folder as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: xyz/client
      context: client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.js'
            dest: .
    - image: xyz/comments
      context: comments
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: '*.js'
            dest: .
    - image: xyz/event-bus
      context: event-bus
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: '*.js'
            dest: .
    - image: xyz/moderation
      context: moderation
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: '*.js'
            dest: .
    - image: xyz/posts
      context: posts
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: '*.js'
            dest: .
    - image: xyz/query
      context: query
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: '*.js'
            dest: .
```

And when i try to use `skaffold dev` command in folder I'm getting the following error:

```
parsing skaffold config: error parsing skaffold configuration file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artifacts use `context:` to reference the source locations.

I think you must be using an old version of Skaffold.  Newer versions of Skaffold provide more detail:

```
parsing skaffold config: unable to parse config: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 4: field content not found in type v2alpha3.Artifact
  line 12: field content not found in type v2alpha3.Artifact
  line 20: field content not found in type v2alpha3.Artifact
  line 28: field content not found in type v2alpha3.Artifact
  line 36: field content not found in type v2alpha3.Artifact
  line 44: field content not found in type v2alpha3.Artifact
```

You might like to check out [Cloud Code for IntelliJ and VS Code](https://cloud.google.com/code) or the online [Cloud Shell Editor](https://ide.cloud.google.com) which provides `skaffold.yaml` editing assistance, including highlighting errors in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have `content` not `context` in the key underneath `- image:` change that and it should work.

Comment: actually i fixed `content` to `context` then also it is showing the same.

Answer (score 0):

This workflow worked for me:

1. Changed first line to: apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta17
2. Execute 'skaffold init' first
3. Execute 'sakffold dev'

I recommend checking this documentation:
https://skaffold.dev/docs/workflows/